# Storing List of different types

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have class Car

```
Class Car{
    protected List<Attribute> attributes;
}
```

then we have class Attribute

```
Class Attribute{
    protected String name;
    protected int sortOrder;
}
```

then we have three types of attributes

```
// single class represents Dropdown
class Single extends Attribute{
    protected List<AttributeOption> options;
}

// multiple class represents Checkbox
class Multiple extends Attribute{
    protected List<AttributeOption> options;
}

class Range extends Attribute{
    protected List<AttributeOption> startRange;
    protected List<AttributeOption> endRange;
}

class AttributeOption{
    protected String name;
    protected int sortOrder;
}
```

How can model the above code in hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give enough details, as what is the exact relation between `Car` and `Attribute` (one to many, or many to many), which inheritance strategy you want to use for `Attribute` (single table, table per class), but this should get you started

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private List<Attribute> attributes;
    ...
    // getters, setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Attribute {
    ...
    private String name;
    private Integer sortOrder;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Car car;
    ...
    // getters, setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Single extends Attribute {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute")
    private List<AttributeOption> options;
    // getters, setters
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Multiple extends Attribute {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute")
    private List<AttributeOption> options;
    // getters, setters
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Range extends Attribute {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute")
    @JoinTable(name = "startrange_option", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "range_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
    private List<AttributeOption> startRange;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute")
    @JoinTable(name = "endrange_option", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "range_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
    private List<AttributeOption> endRange;
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class AttributeOption {
    ... 
    private String name;
    private Integer sortOrder
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id")
    private Attribute attribute;
    // getters, setters
    ...
}
```

The tricky part is two relations to the same entity (`startRange` and `endRange`), which would need either two fields of type `Attribute` in `AttributeOption` entity, or (as in my example) separate join tables for each relation.

Note that this I typed this directly in the answer, so there are probably errors.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer, I have added some more information to the question, if that helps regarding the Mappings.